# Twitter API returns error Bad Authentication data(215) despite having access token

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'd like to acquire a user's tweets.

```
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");

$api_key = 'xxxxxxxx';
$api_secret = 'xxxxxxxx';
$access_token = $_POST["access_token"];
$access_token_secret = $_POST["access_token_secret"];
// $access_token = 'xxxxxxxx';
// $access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxx';

$twitterObj = new TwitterOAuth($api_key, $api_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$request = $twitterObj -> OAuthRequest('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json');
echo json_encode($request);
```

But the result is

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Bad Authentication data\",\"code\":215}]}”
```

The access token is which acquired in iOS client and POSTed.
even if I assign the access token acquired in iOS directly instead of `$_POST[“access_token”]` to $access_token, it becomes the same result.

How do I fix it to acquire the tweets?

Comment: Are the `‘` a copy/paste error, or are these actually in your code -> `$api_key = ‘xxxxxxxx';` (open with `‘` close with `'`), etc.?

Comment: it was copy/paste error and I fix it.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help:

We have the same problem, and 2 types of servers, PHP using twitteroauth and Java using twitter4j 
PHP have this problem java don't

I suggest you check the way authorization is done (use authorization header like twitter4j does which for us is working):

```
    Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="11111111",oauth_nonce="-268659437",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="xxxx",oauth_signature="xxxx"
```